# SQL GROUP BY function returning incorrect SUM amount

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum

I've been working on this problem, researching what I could be doing wrong but I can't seem to find an answer or fault in the code that I've written. I'm currently extracting data from a MS SQL Server database, with a WHERE clause successfully filtering the results to what I want. I get roughly 4 rows per employee, and want to add together a value column. The moment I add the GROUP BY clause against the employee ID, and put a SUM against the value, I'm getting a number that is completely wrong. I suspect the SQL code is ignoring my WHERE clause.

Below is a small selection of data:

```
hr_empl_code    hr_doll_paid
1               20.5
1               51.25
1               102.49
1               560
```

I expect that a GROUP BY and SUM clause would give me the value of 734.24. The value I'm given is 211461.12. Through troubleshooting, I added a COUNT(*) column to my query to work out how many lines it's running against, and it's giving a result of 1152, furthering reinforces my belief that it's ignoring my WHERE clause.

My SQL code is as below. Most of it has been generated by the front-end application that I'm running it from, so there is some additional code in there that I believe does assist the query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    T000.hr_empl_code,
    SUM(T175.hr_doll_paid)
FROM 
    hrtempnm T000,
    qmvempms T001,
    hrtmspay T166,
    hrtpaytp T175,
    hrtptype T177
WHERE   1 = 1 
AND T000.hr_empl_code = T001.hr_empl_code
AND T001.hr_empl_code = T166.hr_empl_code
AND T001.hr_empl_code = T175.hr_empl_code
AND T001.hr_ploy_ment = T166.hr_ploy_ment
AND T001.hr_ploy_ment = T175.hr_ploy_ment
AND T175.hr_paym_code = T177.hr_paym_code
AND T166.hr_pyrl_code = 'f' AND T166.hr_paid_dati = 20180404
AND (T175.hr_paym_type = 'd' OR T175.hr_paym_type = 't')
GROUP BY T000.hr_empl_code
ORDER BY hr_empl_code
```

I'm really lost where it could be going wrong. I have stripped out the additional WHERE AND and brought it down to just T166.hr_empl_code = T175.hr_empl_code, but it doesn't make a different.

By no means am I any expert in SQL Server and queries, but I have decent grasp on the technology. Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: You rarely never combine `SELECT DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`. (Your group by returns no duplicates.)

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. As formatted text, not images.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - absolutely, this didn't come to mind when I was posting (obviously). Edited question for clarification.
@jarlh - I'm by no means a DBA, just someone with knowledge of a lot of different scripting languages, so I'm not aware of modern standards. I have used `JOIN` before, but I didn't know it would be necessary in this case. Same for the use of `SELECT DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` together. The sample data and expected result were included in the initial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by is not wrong, how you are using it is wrong.

```
SELECT 
    T000.hr_empl_code,
    T.totpaid
FROM 
    hrtempnm T000
inner join (SELECT 
    hr_empl_code,
    SUM(hr_doll_paid) as totPaid
FROM 
    hrtpaytp T175
where hr_paym_type = 'd' OR hr_paym_type = 't'
GROUP BY hr_empl_code
) T on t.hr_empl_code = T000.hr_empl_code
where exists
   (select * from qmvempms T001,
    hrtmspay T166,
    hrtpaytp T175,
    hrtptype T177
WHERE  T000.hr_empl_code = T001.hr_empl_code
AND T001.hr_empl_code = T166.hr_empl_code
AND T001.hr_empl_code = T175.hr_empl_code
AND T001.hr_ploy_ment = T166.hr_ploy_ment
AND T001.hr_ploy_ment = T175.hr_ploy_ment
AND T175.hr_paym_code = T177.hr_paym_code
AND T166.hr_pyrl_code = 'f' AND T166.hr_paid_dati = 20180404
)
ORDER BY hr_empl_code
```

Note: It would be more clear if you have used joins instead of old style joining with where.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @Cetin. I am by no means a DBA, which I've since clarified in my question, so I wasn't aware of this usage of `JOIN` vs `WHERE`. I had mentioned, but maybe not clearly before editing my question, that the front-end application generated the most of the initial code before I added the grouping. I've tested your code and it works well in the solution, thanks again!